# Replacing a text selection with a string without destroying tags outside the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

Let's say I have this html:

```
<div class="edit" contenteditable="true">
   <b>Example text</b>
   Text outside
   <b>
      <i>
         <u>underlined and italic and bold</u>
      italic and bold</i></b>
   more Text
   <br>
   after the line break
</div>
```

And for convenience I have this javascript function which gives back the offset of the end of the selection within the given element:

```
var getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin = function(element) {
  var caretOffset = 0;
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
  }
  return caretOffset;
 }
```

---

Let's say the user has made a selection that starts at `outside` and ends within `italic and bold` so it looks like this:

```
"outsideunderlined and italic and bolditalic and bo"
```

How can you replace this whole string without damaging the `<b>Example text</b>` and the text that comes after the selection.
If the string we replace with is empty string `""` the result should look something like this:

```
<div class="edit" contenteditable="true">
   <b>Example text</b>
   Text 
   ld
   more Text
   <br>
   after the line break
</div>
```

I don't care if the tags within the selection are kept or not I am not sure which way is easier.

If anything is unclear to you please ask.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: "ld" was in bold before, it should be still in bold after replacing the text, don't you agree?

Comment: @MaxArt Actually it was bold and italic. I don't care if it stays that way. But in no case it should completely vanish

Comment: Not an easy task, anyway. You'll have to check if `range.startContainer === range.endContainer` - if it's so it's trivial. Or else, you'll have to delete part of the text nodes and every element between them. I'll write an answer later.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion... delete some nodes within and edit the nodes where part is selected. I just can't figure out a way that keeps everything mostly intact. Thank you, I am not in a hurry on this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer isn't for IE8- (for now). This function replaces the selected text with `replaceString` and selects the newly inserted node. You may want to normalize the DOM afterwards, the could be adjacent or empty text nodes.

Ask me if anything isn't clear.

```
function replSel(replaceString) {
    var sel = getSelection(), rng, startNode, endNode, comAnc, sOff;
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        rng = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        sOff = rng.startOffset;
        if (rng.startContainer === rng.endContainer) {
            rng.endContainer.nodeValue =
                  rng.endContainer.nodeValue.substring(0, sOff) + replaceString
                  + rng.endContainer.nodeValue.substring(rng.endOffset);
            rng.setStart(rng.startContainer, sOff);
            rng.setEnd(rng.endContainer, sOff + replaceString.length);
        } else {
            comAnc = rng.commonAncestorContainer;
            rng.startContainer.nodeValue =
                    rng.startContainer.nodeValue.substring(0, sOff);
            // rng.startOffset is set to 0 when the node value is changed
            // That's fine for the range's end, but not for the start.
            rng.setStart(rng.startContainer, sOff);
            rng.endContainer.nodeValue =
                    rng.endContainer.nodeValue.substring(rng.endOffset);
            startNode = rng.startContainer;
            while (startNode.parentNode !== comAnc) {
                while (startNode.nextSibling)
                    startNode.parentNode.removeChild(startNode.nextSibling);
                startNode = startNode.parentNode;
            }
            endNode = rng.endContainer;
            while (endNode.parentNode !== comAnc) {
                while (endNode.previousSibling)
                    endNode.parentNode.removeChild(endNode.previousSibling);
                endNode = endNode.parentNode;
            }
            while (startNode.nextSibling !== endNode)
                comAnc.removeChild(startNode.nextSibling);
            comAnc.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(replaceString), endNode);
        }
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(rng);
    }
}
```